# Creating a Rails 3 scope that joins to a subquery

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

First off, I'm a Ruby/Rails newbie, so I apologize if this question is basic.

I've got a DB that (among other things) looks like this:

```
organizations { id, name, current_survey_id }
surveys { id, organization_id }
responses { id, survey_id, question_response_integer }
```

I'm trying to create a scope method that adds the average of the current survey answers to a passed-in Organization relation. In other words, the scope that's getting passed into the method would generate SQL that looks like more-or-less like this:

```
select * from organizations
```

And I'd like the scope, after it gets processed by my lambda, to generate SQL that looks like this:

```
select o.id, o.name, cs.average_responses
from organizations o join
(select r.id, avg(r.question_response_integer) as average_responses 
     from responses r 
     group by r.id) cs on cs.id = o.current_survey_id
```

The best I've got is something like this:

```
current_survey_average: lambda do |scope, sort_direction|
  average_answers = Responses.
     select("survey_id, avg(question_response_integer) as average_responses").
     group("survey_id")
  scope.joins(average_answers).order("average_responses #{sort_direction}")
end
```

That's mostly just a stab in the dark - among other things, it doesn't specify how the scope could be expected to join to `average_answers` - but I haven't been able to find any documentation about how to do that sort of join, and I'm running out of things to try.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Thanks to Sean Hill for the answer. Just to have it on record, here's the code I ended up going with:

```
current_survey_average: lambda do |scope, sort_direction|
  scope_table = scope.arel.froms.first.name
  query = <<-QUERY
    inner join (
     select r.survey_id, avg(r.question_response_integer) as average_responses
      from responses r
      group by r.survey_id
    ) cs
    on cs.survey_id = #{scope_table}.current_survey_id
  QUERY
  scope.
    joins(query).
    order("cs.average_responses #{sort_direction}")
end
```

That said, I can see the benefit of putting the `averaged_answers` scope directly onto the Responses class - so I may end up doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not been able to test this, but I think the following would work, either as-is or with a little tweaking.

```
class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :averaged, -> { select('r.id, avg(r.question_response_integer) as average_responses').group('r.id') }

  scope :current_survey_average, ->(incoming_scope, sort_direction) do
    scope_table = incoming_scope.arel.froms.first.name
    query = <<-QUERY
      INNER JOIN ( #{Arel.sql(averaged.to_sql)} ) cs
      ON cs.id = #{scope_table}.current_survey_id
    QUERY

    incoming_scope.joins(query).order("average_responses #{sort_direction}")
  end
end
```

So what I've done here is that I have split out the inner query into another scope called averaged.  Since you do not know which table the incoming scope in `current_survey_average` is coming from, I got the scope table name via `scope.arel.froms.first.name`.  Then I created a query string that uses the `averaged` scope and joined it using the `scope_table` variable.  The rest is pretty self-explanatory.

If you do know that the incoming scope will always be from the organizations table, then you don't need the extra `scope_table` variable.  You can just hardcode it into the join query string.

I would make one suggestion.  If you do not have control over `sort_direction`, then I would not directly input that into the order string.

Comment: Thanks much, that was the answer. I posted my modified version above: many thanks.